# Website Visits Database Designs

Tags: php, mysql, sql, asp.net, database

for a website visits counting, which of table schemes do you prefer ?
[image]

For scheme a :
check if IP exits , we increase count by one step and don't add new IP.

For scheme b :
we add new IP every time , and for reporting we use GroupBY in our application.

Comment: c) ip, visit_datetime

Comment: I think **b** will be faster, not having to check if exists or do an update (which is typically more expensive than an insert). You also get a much more granular view of the data, so can do more interesting analysis. I think you're over-estimating the appeal of your website if you think you need a `bigint` to count how many times a single person views a page though. :p

Comment: maybe ,but what if website user are too many ? is b faster again ?

Comment: Option (a) is good table structure..

Comment: @Strawberry , table without key ? please explain more.

Comment: @TZHX , in bigint in scheme (a) I am agree with you  but I not really sure that b is better !

Comment: Those columns ARE the key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st is perfect.

**Why ?**

1. See , for one visitor you store only one record. There cant be multiple records for a visitor, like you have for such as One customer has Multiple Address. In this case address is multiple. But customer will be only one. Same case applies in your example too.
2. You no need to increase database size by adding same row multiple times for same user/visitor.
3. For **SELECT** you will need to fetch multiple records though most of the records are same.

   So if you follow way 2 , you insert 1000 entries for one visitor with same ip.
   If you follow way 1 , you have 1 entry which gets updated with countVisited. Now tell me is fetching 1000 rows is faster or fetching 1 ??
4. If you want to **UPDATE** some parameter you need to search for record of visitor in 1000 records and then modify it. You can tell yourself which way is better.

Comment: at comments on top , TZHX said that for existence of two operations(SELECT,UPDATE) in a , b is faster , but I think b is not faster if website users be too many !

Comment: You're going to be updating / inserting far more often than you're selecting on this sort of table. Usage is constant, analysis is irregular.

Answer (score 0):

In my database, I use [Count:bigint, Time:bigint], where Time is rounded to whole days (timestamp divided by 24*60*60). I have around a million visitors per day, and I just get one record per day :)